# Unable to detect the repository annotation in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

I have a Repository class on the package:

```
com.repository
```

And I have defined the `@ComponentScan("com.*")` in the main class of Spring Boot.

However while running the application I am getting the Exception

> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.repository.TopicRepository' in
>   your configuration.

Below are the classes:

**TopicRepository**

```
package com.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.models.Topic;


@Repository
public interface TopicRepository extends CrudRepository<Topic,String>{



}
```

**Application**

```
package com.example.springboot.springboot.test;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.*")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

**POM.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example.springboot</groupId>
<artifactId>springboot.test</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>springboot.test</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.197</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
</properties>
```

I have already tried the `@ComponentScan`. If I change the `scanBasePackages` to `"com.repository"` then it is able to somehow pickup `TopicRepository` alongwith other `Service and Controller`, which should not be the case since they are under different package.

EDIT:

**package structure**

com.models : Models

com.repository : Repository

com.services : Sevices

com.controllers : Controllers

com.springboot.springboottest : Main Class

Comment: The package spec isn't a glob; just use `com`.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-locating-the-main-class

Comment: did u try @ComponentScan("com") ? or @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages= "com")

Comment: The user even doesn’t  need to mention the package name if all the classes to be scanned are kept under the sub packages of the main class

Answer (score -1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-locating-the-main-class)

> We generally recommend that you locate your main application class in
>   a root package above other classes. The @SpringBootApplication
>   annotation is often placed on your main class, and **it implicitly
>   defines a base “search package” for certain items**.

Also as  *chrylis -on strike* points out in the comment , the base package should be just defined as `com` . The scan would start from package `com` and on all its subpackages

[@ComponentScan](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html)("com")

**Update**

Based on the package structure shared.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.models","com.repository","com.services","com.controllers"})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

or

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

should work.

The best option is to move the class `Application` to the package `com` have the following annotation.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: No Still the same problem

Comment: You did mention that when 'scanBasePackages' was modified it worked. What did you modify and what is the latest error ?

Comment: @RG, I modified to include the package like scanBasePackages("com.repository"). It started the application but the controllers and services were not getting picked up since they were in different package.Currently I am getting the same error as defined in the question

Comment: @ghostrider you can add multiple packages to componentscan: eg :  @ComponentScan({“package1”,”package2”}). At the same time adding “com” should ideally scan all sub packages and detect the components

Comment: Same goes for @SpringBootApplication

Comment: Yes ideally it should but not happening in my case

Comment: @ghostrider controllers and services are under sub packages of com ? Could you please update the question with the structure of your project indicating the main class and the components that are not auto detected?